# What is the secret to the speed of the filesystem::copy function?

Tags: c++, file, read-write

I am trying to reach the speed of `filesystem::copy` in reading the content of a file and write that content to a new file "copy operation" but I can't reach that speed.

The following is a simple example of my attempt:

```
void Copy(const wstring &fromPath, const wstring &toPath) {
    ifstream readFile(fromPath.c_str(), ios_base::binary|ios_base::ate);    
    char* fileContent = NULL;
    if (!readFile) { cout << "Cannot open the file.\n"; return; }
    ofstream writeFile(toPath.c_str(), ios_base::binary);
    streampos size = readFile.tellg();
    readFile.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);
    fileContent = new char[size];
    readFile.read(fileContent, size);
    writeFile.write(fileContent, size);
    readFile.close();
    writeFile.close();
    delete[] fileContent;
}
```

The previous code able to copy a file.iso its size "1.48GB" in between "8 to 9" seconds, while `filesystem::copy` able to copy the same file in between "1 to 2" seconds maximum.
**Notice**: I don't want to use C++17 in the current period.

**How can I do to make the speed of my function to be like** `filesystem::copy`**?**

Comment: Check the implementation?

Comment: `filesystem::copy` is most likely calling the OS api to copy the.  That should be a lot faster then manually reading to the end of the file to get the size, allocate space, read data, create new file, copy, deallocate.

Comment: The secret is that `filesystem:copy` (like other standard library features) can be implemented differently for different platforms. A standard library implementation can use hardware or OS level optimized features while remaining portable.

Comment: @deW1: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: @LionKing deW1 means that you could just download the source code of your standard library and then read it's implementation of `std::filesystem::copy` to see how it does it. And I agree with that - it's a sensible approach to finding an answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have more time, I meant what Jesper said. Your favorite IDE should also be able to access the code by pressing CTRL + Left Click (typically). As mentioned, yes the implementation might be platform specific, but you will still get an idea of the general approach used.

Comment: A secret of efficiently reading files is to maximise the data size per transaction.  For example, a single read of 1024 bytes is more efficient than 1024 reads of 1 byte.  Another secret is to keep the data streaming; reduce interruptions.  Lastly, organize the file so that the contents are in one block on the hard drive.  Having to find and switch to non-consecutive locations wastes time.

Comment: I don't see why people need to read entire files into memory, when they only access the data once.  But this is probably a discussion for another topic/question.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation needs to allocate a buffer of the size of the whole file. That is wasteful, you could just read 64k, write 64k, repeat for the next blocks.

There's cost to paging memory in and out. If you read the whole thing then write the whole thing, you end up paging in and out the whole file twice.

It could be that multiple threads might read/write separately (provided read stays ahead). That may speed things up.

With hardware support, there might not even be a need for the data to go all the way to the CPU. Yet, your implementation probably ends up doing it. It would be very hard hard for the compiler to reason about what you do or don't with fileContent.

There's countless other tricks the implementation of `filesystem::copy` might be using. You could go see how it is coded, there's plenty of open implementations.

There's a caveat though: The implementation of the standard library might rely on specific behaviours that the language doesn't guarantee. So you can't simply copy the code to a different compiler/architecture/platform.

Comment: Beware that you can't necessarily use tricks you find in standard library function implementations. Those implementations typically target specific architectures or platforms and can rely on guaranties that are not generally provided by the language.